# How do I make the material transparent instead of an mirror effect?

Tags: materials, transparency, mirror

I have a problem with making an eye from this tutorial.
https://youtu.be/gfEyhPXsOCM

Everything worked fine, but at the end my iris looks like a mirror because the material of an eyeball covers it instead of being transparent. [image]

It changes when I swap the blend mode from opaque to alpha clip, alpha hashed or alpha blend, but i'm not satisfied with those results. I'd prefer to do it with opaque.
This is how it looks like with alpha hashed: [image]

This is my material settings [image]

I've been looking for an answer for so many hours now, and I'm pretty sure it's something easy and fast to solve, but I simply can't find out what this is all about. I've seen people having similar problems, but I think I missed something because nothing seems to help </3

Comment: In what way are you not satisfied with your result in alpha clip? it looks fine to me.

Comment: maybe show us a picture how you want it to be? and by the way: in eevee there is no other way to get something transparent without using the blend mode alpha blend/hashed....AFAIK

Comment: Seems you want refraction instead of transparency. Maybe try a Refraction shader instead. And you need to enable "Refraction" in the render properties

Comment: You prefer to do it with opaque? But opacity is the opposite of transparency, an opaque object is by definition not transparent, so how do you suppose to see the iris behind it?